# Javascript onclick Trigger two different Select Options

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to Trigger two different select options. I'v set it so that the first two select items work fine. Though I want to trigger non sequentially so the items are as follows:

onclick selectOption(12) at id="select_id" select item DATA_item14 (Works)
AND Then Sequentially Trigger  Option  #5  at  id="select_id2" which is $1619.00

Here's the Partially working code.

does anyone have any (pure JS)  suggestions

```
<ul>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(1);">Item 2: $1608.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(2);">Item 3: $1714.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(12);">Item 13: $2418.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(13);">Item 14: $1619.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(14);">Item 15: $1608.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(15);">Item 16: $1964.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(16);">Item 17: $1837.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(17);">Item 18 $2312.00</button></li>
    </ul>

 


 <select required   id="select_id"   onchange="update(this.value)" >
 <option>DATA_item1</option> 
 <option>DATA_item2</option> 
 <option>DATA_item3</option> 
 <option>DATA_item4</option> 
 <option>DATA_item5</option>  
 <option>DATA_item6</option> 
 <option>DATA_item7</option> 
 <option>DATA_item8</option>   
 <option>DATA_item9</option> 
 <option>DATA_item10</option> 
 <option>DATA_item11</option> 
 <option>DATA_item12</option> 
 <option>DATA_item13</option> 
 <option>DATA_item14</option> 
 <option>DATA_item15</option>  
 <option>DATA_item16</option> 
 <option>DATA_item17</option> 
 <option>DATA_item18</option>   
 <option>DATA_item19</option> 
 <option>DATA_item20</option> 
</select>   

 
 <hr>

 
<select required  id="select_id2"  onchange="update(this.value)" style="font-size:200%" >
<option  selected="selected">Standard $1327</option>
<option>$1608.00</option> 
<option>$1714.00</option> 
<option>$2418.00</option>  
<option>$1619.00</option> 
<option>$1608.00</option> 
<option>$1964.00</option>
<option>$1837.00</option> 
<option>$2312.00</option> 
</select>   
 
 
<script>
function selectOption(index){ 
  document.getElementById("select_id").options.selectedIndex = index;
   document.getElementById("select_id2").options.selectedIndex = index;
}
</script>
```

Comment: _“AND Then Sequentially Trigger Option #5 at id="select_id2"”_ - based on _what_, what makes #5 the relevant one?

Comment: I read the question five times, but I still don't have a clue of what you're actually asking. There's a mention "_I want to trigger non sequentially_", what does that mean? Do you want to add a delay between the automated selections of the select elements?

Comment: So when I Click on the fourth button, it will then Trigger Two select options to display values. Select_id will then display - DATA_item14, and Select_id2 will display $1619.00

Comment: Select_id does trigger and display DATA_item14, though select_id2 doesn't display a value.

Comment: _“So when I Click on the fourth button”_ - oh, so now it is the fourth? Previously, you referred to the _third_ one. With the fourth, this make a lot more sense, because the text content of that button contains `$1619.00`, and _apparently_ that is what you want to select the option in select_id2 based _upon_. (Why aren’t _you_ saying exactly that to begin with? Why is coming up with a proper problem description _our_ responsibility here?)

Comment: There is no connection between the `DATA_item14`, and that value `$1619.00` so far - so you need to pass that value as a second parameter to your function, so that it can then select the option in select_id2 based on that.

Comment: -CBroe  the fourth button triggers Select option #5 on  select_id2

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/kedtxp7r/) Here's a Demo.

Answer (score 1):

By Adding a second parameter to the existing function so that we can send another value to the function when we call it. This way we can send two values to the function.

```
 <ul>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(1,1);">Item 2: $1608.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(2,2);">Item 3: $1714.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(12,3);">Item 13: $2418.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(12,4);">Item 14: $1619.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(14);">Item 15: $1608.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(15);">Item 16: $1964.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(16);">Item 17: $1837.00</button></li>
        <li><button  onclick="selectOption(17);">Item 18 $2312.00</button></li>
    </ul>

 


    <select required   id="select_id"   onchange="update(this.value)" >
    <option>DATA_item1</option> 
    <option>DATA_item2</option> 
    <option>DATA_item3</option> 
    <option>DATA_item4</option> 
    <option>DATA_item5</option>  
    <option>DATA_item6</option> 
    <option>DATA_item7</option> 
    <option>DATA_item8</option>   
    <option>DATA_item9</option> 
    <option>DATA_item10</option> 
    <option>DATA_item11</option> 
    <option>DATA_item12</option> 
    <option>DATA_item13</option> 
    <option>DATA_item14</option> 
    <option>DATA_item15</option>  
    <option>DATA_item16</option> 
    <option>DATA_item17</option> 
    <option>DATA_item18</option>   
    <option>DATA_item19</option> 
    <option>DATA_item20</option> 
    </select>   
<hr>

<select required  id="select_id2"  onchange="update(this.value)" style="font-size:200%" >
<option  selected="selected">Standard $1327</option>
<option>$1608.00</option> 
<option>$1714.00</option> 
<option>$2418.00</option>  
<option>$1619.00</option> 
<option>$1608.00</option> 
<option>$1964.00</option>
<option>$1837.00</option> 
<option>$2312.00</option> 
</select> 
    
    <script>function selectOption(index1, index2){ 
            document.getElementById("select_id").options.selectedIndex = index1;
            document.getElementById("select_id2").options.selectedIndex = index2;
        }
    </script>
```